# Как скрыть блок при нажатии за его пределами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно скрыть блок, если кликнуть за его пределами.
Пользуюсь вот такой [конструкцией](https://jsfiddle.net/Alarr/mp7gthqb/4/).

Но так блок будет появляться и исчезать только по нажатию на кнопку, а надо, что бы появлялся по нажатию на кнопку, а исчезал и по нажатию на кнопку, и после клика за пределами блока.
Ну и понятное дело, что блок не должен исчезать при нажатии на него, так как там должен быть, к примеру, `input` для поиска.
И прозрачный бэкграунд на весь экран тоже не прокатит.

Comment: почему прозрачный на весь боди не катит?

Comment: дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/Как-в-javascript-закрывать-div-при-клике-вне-этого-дива

Answer (score 6):

Один из вариантов: добавить обработчик клика для всего документа, и скрывать этот блок по нему. А чтобы при этом не поменялось при клике на кнопку и сам блок - добавить в их обработчики [*e.stopPropagation()*](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
$(".button").click(function(e) {
  $('.toggled_block').toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.toggled_block').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.toggled_block').hide();
});
```

```css
.parent_block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00BB65;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.toggled_block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent_block">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="toggled_block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо ты решил мою проблему  @Grundy