# Как в javascript “закрывать” div при клике вне этого дива? (без jquery)

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

[Как в javascript "закрывать" div при клике вне этого дива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-div-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Тот же вопрос, только надо написать без *jQuery*.

Comment: последний ответ по ссылке не подходит?

Comment: там использован jquery

Comment: Вам уже дали ответ, но справедливости ради - _последний_ ответ по ссылке - без jquery.

Comment: @Ponio Там близко, но не совсем то.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это делается, например, так:

```js
document.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("block").style.display = "none";
}
function onDivClick(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
#block {
    background-color: #ddf;
    border: 2px solid #ffd;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block" onclick="onDivClick(event);"></div>
```