# Как закрыть окно с поисковыми подсказками при клике вне инпута и вне окна?

Tags: jquery

Есть `input`, при фокусе на котором открывается блок с поисковыми подсказками.

```
$(".search_input").focus(function () {
        $(".hints").show();
});
```

Как сделать закрытие блока при клике вне `input`'a и вне блока?
Пример можно посмотреть [здесь](http://exist.ru), кликнув на поисковую строку.

**UPD:** отметили, что такой вопрос уже есть. Предложенное решение не подходит,
так как нужно закрывать блок при клике вне блока, и если клик был не по инпуту. Также при использовании предложенного решения у меня блок открывается и сразу закрывается.

**JS:**

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".hints");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.hide();
    }
});

$(".search_input").focus(function () {
    $(".hints").show();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="search">

                    <form action="#" method="get">

                        <input class="search_input" type="text" placeholder="Поиск детали, например: 990190112">

                        <!-- settings -->

                        <div class="settings">

                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1">
                            <label for="radio1" data-placeholder="Введите номер детали">Искать по номеру детали</label>

                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2">
                            <label for="radio2" data-placeholder="Введите что-то">Если нужен этот пункт</label>

                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3">
                            <label for="radio3" data-placeholder="Введите VIN-номер">Искать по VIN-номеру</label>

                        </div>

                        <!-- /settings -->

                        <button class="search_btn"></button>

                    </form>

                    <div class="settings_btn">
                        <div class="arrow_up"></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- hints -->

                    <div class="hints">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <!-- /hints -->

                </div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в javascript "закрывать" div при клике вне этого дива?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-div-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: я кстати так и не понял где смотреть пример на указанном сайте

Comment: Там при клике по поисковой строке http://joxi.ru/l2ZnXxgS81gyM2

Comment: так же. не совсем понятно, что значит _при клике вне окна_. какое окно тут имеется ввиду? если окно браузера. то у объекта window есть так же событие `blur`

Comment: Как ни странно, но у меня показывается другой вид на этом сайте

Comment: _закрывать блок при клике вне блока, и если клик был не по инпуту_ - это как раз то, отчет на что дан в прикрепленном ответе

Comment: Если делать по предложенному варианту, то у меня получается, что блок открывается, и сразу закрывается, так как клик был не по блоку, а по инпуту.

Comment: И если даже окно открыто, то если кликнуть по инпуту, блок всё равно закроется.

Comment: значит вы его просто не правильно используете, и без примера того, как сейчас - нельзя сказать что именно не так

Comment: Знать бы ещё, как его правильно использовать. Сейчас добавлю код, как делаю я.

Comment: и пример разметки тоже

Comment: Не подскажите, как применить тот код?

Comment: не стоит удалять вопросы просто так, если на вопрос не ответили в течение двух минут, не значит, что на него не ответят потом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно просто применить условия:

- закрывать блок при клике вне блока - `$target.closest('.hints').length === 0`
- если клик был не по инпуту - `!$target.hasClass('search_input')`

Если оба условия выполняются - значит надо закрывать.

Пример:

```js
var container = $(".hints");
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.closest('.hints').length === 0 // если не внутри блока hints
    && !$target.hasClass('search_input')) { // и не по инпуту с классом search_input
    container.hide();
  }
});

$(".search_input").focus(function() {
  container.show();
});
```

```css
.hints {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">

  <form action="#" method="get">

    <input class="search_input" type="text" placeholder="Поиск детали, например: 990190112">

    <!-- settings -->

    <div class="settings">

      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1">
      <label for="radio1" data-placeholder="Введите номер детали">Искать по номеру детали</label>

      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2">
      <label for="radio2" data-placeholder="Введите что-то">Если нужен этот пункт</label>

      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3">
      <label for="radio3" data-placeholder="Введите VIN-номер">Искать по VIN-номеру</label>

    </div>

    <!-- /settings -->

    <button class="search_btn"></button>

  </form>

  <div class="settings_btn">
    <div class="arrow_up"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- hints -->

  <div class="hints">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">17020400F3009</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- /hints -->

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. У меня было так https://jsfiddle.net/y555shm5/
Не подскажите ещё, этот скрипт можно применить, если на странице 4 окна, и если какое-то из них открыли, то закрывается при клике мимо него?

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, я не могу понять какое именно поведение вы хотите в итоге

Comment: Это то, что нужно. Дальше сам буду разбираться.