# Как предотвратить скрытие панели меню по вкладкам

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Имеется страничка на bootstrap(3.3.7) с выпадающим меню, в котором содержатся вкладки и ссылки. В данное время меню открывается по наведению, вкладки работают.

[Песочница](http://codepen.io/drakulitka/pen/WRvWWN)

Если удалить этот JS скрипт в песочнице:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    );
});
```

то выпадающее меню открывается по клику, но и закрывается по следующему любому клику на вкладках или другом элементе меню и вне его пределах.

Если оставить JS-код, то меню открывается при наведении, и не скрывается при клике на вкладках (табах).

Как сделать показ меню при клике, при этом предотвратить закрытие меню по вкладкам и пустом месте выпадающего меню?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, самый простой путь - переместить код, отвечающий за открытие из `hover()` в `click()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown").click(   
   function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
            $(this).addClass('open');        
        }
    )

    $(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() { },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
            $(this).removeClass('open');       
        }
    );
});
```

Попутно заменив `toggleClass()` на `addClass()` и `removeClass()`

Comment: Частично работает, меню открывается по клику но скрывается как только стрелка пропадает с области выпадающего меню.

Comment: @Drakulitka Я не могу понять что вам нужно. Вам нужно конкретно в вопросе описать когда меню появляется и когда скрывается.

Comment: Открытие выпадающего меню по клику на родителе .dropdown, закрытие по клику на родителе или вне области выпадающего меню.

Comment: Очевидно, это совершенно другой вопрос, но на такое уже, конечно, [отвечали](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-div-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: Поправил меню, не подскажете как предотвратить некорректный эффект повторного клика по родителю (.dropdown) - меню скрывается и вновь появляется, хотелось бы чтобы было или скрытие меню или появление, в зависимости от текущего состояния [песочница](http://codepen.io/drakulitka/pen/WRvWWN)

Comment: @drakulitka это не форум, комментарии используются для уточнения ответов. Если хотите спросить - задайте новый вопрос