# Закрытие модального окна по клику на window, но не по клику на модальное окно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю свои модальные окна, ибо использовать библиотеки ради двух-трех окон - как стрелять из пушки по воробьям.

Не получается сделать функцию, которая по клику на `window` будет проверять, совершен ли клик на модальное окно или нет.

Сделал на данный момент: https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/eGPOod

Делал по примеру: https://codepen.io/bradtraversy/pen/zEOrPp

Единственное, юзаю в проекте jquery, у него же идет чистый js. Как сделать подобие его модального окна на jquery? Отличия моего кода от его - у него лишь одна кнопка, которая открывает модальное окно, у меня же их несколько.

Comment: Чем твоя библиотека будет лучше существующих?

Comment: @SultanovShamil спасибо большое))

Comment: @Alex78191 мне не нужна вся библиотека. У различных либ слишком много всего есть - изображения, аякс подрузка и т.д., мне это не надо)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-div-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: хорош, автор. ищу уже час с этими outsideclick решение, а тут все просто