# Закрыть блок по клику на область

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кнопка, по клику вылазит корзина. Подскажите, как закрыть корзину по клику на любую область экрана за пределами корзины ? Сейчас корзина закрывается только по клику на кнопку.

```
    $('.header-cart').click(function(){
        $('#cart').fadeToggle();
    });
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в javascript "закрывать" div при клике вне этого дива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-div-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Там, кстати, в блоке справа есть вопросы "Связанные" и "Похожие". Если ответ из дубля не поможет - можно посмотреть не остальные в списке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Пример кода**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bt").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".content").length) {
      $('.wrap').hide();
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<button class="bt">Корзина</button>
<div class="wrap">
  контент
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: И первый и второй пример работают, но к сожалению если кликать по самой кнопке, чтобы закрыть див, то корзина исчезает и сразу появляется

Comment: @Denis Denis   посмотрите пример кода

Comment: точно также( если кликать по области, то все супер, если закрывать кнопкой .bt то идет постоянный slideToggle

Comment: @Denis Denis поправил