# Как убрать класс по клику не по данному элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.phones__list-item a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).parents('.phones__list-item').hasClass('open')){
        $(this).parents('.phones__list-item').removeClass('open');
        $(".phones__list-item a > i").removeClass("fa-angle-up").addClass("fa-angle-down");
    }else{
        $(".phones__list-item a > i").removeClass("fa-angle-up").addClass("fa-angle-down");
        $(this).siblings("i").removeClass("fa-angle-down").addClass("fa-angle-up");
        $('.phones__list-item').removeClass('open');
        $(this).parents('.phones__list-item').addClass('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что Вы хотите сделать, и что Вас не устраивает в приведенном коде.

Comment: Когда кликаю на любую точку на странице нужно убирать клас open у элемнта)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в javascript "закрывать" div при клике вне этого дива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-div-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Основная ошибка в этом коде, что вы пытаетесь переключить значки в тэгах `i`, используя `$(this).siblings("i")`. Фактически такой запрос выдает 0 результатов, поскольку `i` находится внутри тэгов `a`, в то время как `siblings` возращает узлы, находящиеся на одном уровне в дереве DOM. Поэтому следует использовать надо либо `$(this).find("i")` либо `$(this).children("i")`. В остальном же код переключает классы `open` и значки исправно.