# Закрытия input при клике по другому элементу

Tags: jquery

Приветствую.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при клике на любой другой элемента, кроме самого input, исчезал блок modal.

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
  if ($(e.target).is('#search')) {
    $('#modalsearch').fadeIn();
  }
})
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.modal {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 6;
}
.modal::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.modal__input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.modal__input:focus::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal__input::placeholder {
  color: #8d8d8d;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.modal__input_wrap {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 3/11;
  margin: 210px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 7;
}
.modal__input_wrap::after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "";
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ffc100;
  right: 22.5px;
  top: 19px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="searchopen" id="search">open</button>
<div class="modal modal__search" id="modalsearch">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="modal__input_wrap">
      <input class="modal__input" id="#searchinput" type="text" placeholder="Lūdzu ievadiet meklējamo vārdu vai frāzi">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в javascript "закрывать" div при клике вне этого дива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-div-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(() => {
  const $modal = $('#modalsearch');

  $(document).on('click', '#search', () => {
    $modal.fadeIn();
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#modalsearch', e => {
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('modal__input')) {
      $modal.fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.modal {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 6;
}
.modal::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.modal__input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.modal__input:focus::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal__input::placeholder {
  color: #8d8d8d;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.modal__input_wrap {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 3/11;
  margin: 210px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 7;
}
.modal__input_wrap::after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "";
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ffc100;
  right: 22.5px;
  top: 19px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="searchopen" id="search">open</button>
<div class="modal modal__search" id="modalsearch">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="modal__input_wrap">
      <input class="modal__input" id="#searchinput" type="text" placeholder="Lūdzu ievadiet meklējamo vārdu vai frāzi">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! :) Буду подтягивать JS.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $modalBtn = $('.open-modal');

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if(target.hasClass('open-modal')) {
        $("#" + target.data('action')).slideToggle().addClass('now-open');
    }else if(target.hasClass('now-open')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.now-open').removeClass('now-open').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

```css
.modal{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    display:none
}

.modal .modal-content{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.7)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="open1" class="open-modal" type="button" value="open modal 1" data-action="modal-1" />
<input id="open2" class="open-modal" type="button" value="open modal 2" data-action="modal-2" />

<div class="modal" id="modal-1">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form>
            <p>modal 1 content</p>
            <p>modal 1 content</p>
            <p>modal 1 content</p>
            <input type="submit" value="check default submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="modal-2">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>modal 2 content</p>
        <p>modal 2 content</p>
        <p>modal 2 content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```