# Выпадающее меню при фокусе

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть кнопка с меню

```
<button class="show-menu" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
  <h3>Помощь</h3>
</button>
<ul class="menu menu--hide">
  <li class="menu__item" style="display: flex; align-items: center;" >
    <p>Тест</p>
  </li>
  <li class="open-record-panel-btn menu__item" style="display: flex; align-items: center;" >
    <p>Тест2</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

И такой код, который навешивает событие (скрывает открывает), но работает оно при клике, а надо фокусом. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы кнопка срабатывала фокусом, а при клике на другую область меню скрывалось

```
var linkBtn = document.querySelector('.show-menu');
if (linkBtn) {
  linkBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var menuList = document.querySelector('.menu--hide');

    if(menuList) {
      menuList.classList.toggle('menu--show');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: На самом деле не очень понятно, что значит "при фокусе". Событие "фокус" наступает в случае, если по элементу произведён клик или осуществлён переход с клавиатуры с помощью Tab. Если у Вас меню работает по клику, значит, оно и так работает по фокусу (получает фокус при клике). Может быть, вы имеете в виду ховер (наведение)?

Comment: Мне просто нужно,чтобы при клике вне меню,оно скрывалось,поэтому требуется фокус

Comment: А у меня оно не скрывается и всегда отображается после клика по кнопке

Comment: Ну так а вот Вам Rogatnev Nikita дал ответ - разве это не то, что надо? По кнопке открывается, при клике вне меню закрывается.

Comment: Клики по элементам меню не срабатывают,т.к оно сразу скрывается,а надо чтобы скрывалось только при клике вне меню(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вообще на чистом CSS. Codepen: https://codepen.io/rogatnev-nikita/full/wRMExj

```css
.menu {
    display: none;
}

.show-menu:focus + .menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="show-menu">
  <h3>Помощь</h3>
</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item">
    <p>Тест</p>
  </li>
  <li class="open-record-panel-btn menu__item">
    <p>Тест2</p>
  </li>     
</ul>
```

Если нужен JS, то отслеживайте событие `focus` метода `EventListener`

```
document.addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
    /* Ваш код */
}, true);
```

Comment: Когда я ставлю focus в addEventListener, то он не работает, при клике на другую область меню не скрывается

Comment: Клики по элементам меню теперь не срабатывают(

Comment: @VoA тогда фокус тут совсем не причем, посмотрите ответы тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/Как-в-javascript-закрывать-div-при-клике-вне-этого-дива