# JS как скрыть блок при нажатии в любом месте? в том числе и по этому блоку

Tags: javascript

пожалуйста подскажите. При добавлении класса сейчас меняется высота, как при клике на любую точку экрана, после выполнения скрипта конечно, скрыть обратно всё это дело?

```
<div class="term-description">text text text</div>

<script>
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('term-description');
btns[0].onclick = function() {
  btns[0].classList.add("term-description-open");
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140922/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-div-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0 - ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: Daniil там все решения по привязке к id, как сделать по классам?

Comment: Просто берите элемент по класса,а не по айди